# Difference between std::vector::back and vector::operator[ vector::size() - 1]

Tags: c++, stl

is there a difference between:

```
mvt_act_idx = openCloseList.size()-1;
openCloseList[mvt_act_idx].A += a;
```

and

```
 openCloseList.back().A += a;
```

Besides readability?

Comment: What is your concern? Why there should be a difference?

Comment: @Vlad: I have found a lot of code written like my first example and I wonder if I should refactor it. If there are no improvmenet besides readibility I won't bother

Comment: Well, still a lot of people think about STL as just something providing an array, so they use `std::vector` in the same fashion as they are used to working with C arrays.

Comment: Anyway, the 1st form is more error prone (you need to have the same array referenced at both lines, and not forget to subtract 1), so the 2nd form is indeed better.

Comment: A standard library implementation might do bounds checking in debug build. Sure enough, `back` wouldn't need to be bounds-checked as the library already knows it's in bounds whereas `operator[]` would be. Thus, a debug build might be even more annoyingly slow  than usual (and, unnecessarily) with the first flavour.

Comment: @Damon: `back` still needs to be bounds-checked, as the vector might be empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No useful difference.

Using `back()` directly might be fractionally more efficient, but I doubt it. You could have a look at the generated assembler if you felt really keen. Might make the difference of an instruction or two, depending on how clever your compiler is.

I do note that the former way which uses only `size()` and `[]` would be a lot more familiar to people who understand arrays or use similar contructs in any other language; `back()` is a bit more C++ specific (though it is hardly a cryptic idiom).

Answer (score 2):

```
mvt_act_idx = openCloseList.size()-1;
openCloseList[mvt_act_idx].A += a;
```

If `openCloseList` is empty the unsigned subtraction will produce a huge value, which then is used to index the vector. The indexing operator may assert, or not.

```
openCloseList.back().A += a;
```

If `openCloseList` is empty the `back` operation may assert, or not.

In the case of such error, a fault in `back` is probably easier to understand.

And anyway, the first code snippet can be in conflict with some guideline to not use unsigned integers *as numbers* (except where the modulo behavior simplifies and clarifies the code), while the call to `back` can not be in conflict with any such guideline.